# Java alternance method not working

Tags: java

I have an integer array and I want to check if any two successive elements have different signs. I tried this, but it doesn't work

For example, `{2,-3,17,-1,4,5,-1,8,-9,3}` must be false but the method gives true

```
public boolean alternance(int[] a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        if(a[i] * a[i+1] < 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like it should work, can you show some input on which it fails?  (Edit: Yup, just tested it and it seems to work.)

Comment: {2,-3,17,-1,4,5,-1,8,-9,3} answer must be false but the method give true :/

Comment: Why would that input return false? Even the first two elements already should make it return true. 2 has an opposite sign from -3.

Comment: If you want it to check for ALL consecutive pairs, instead of ANY, you should put `> 0` for the check in the loop and return `false` there, and then outside of the loop return `true`.

Comment: It should output false because 4 and 5 in the array have same sign

Comment: I want the method to check all elemenets i and i+1 till the end

Comment: Okay i will try it

Comment: It's sometimes helpful to say what you want out long, explicitly, in English.  You want "returns true if and only if every consecutive pair of integers have differing signs".   What you wrote above was "returns true if a pair of consecutive integers have differing signs".

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't too concerned with integer overflow?

Comment: Use `java.lang.Math.signum()` method to get the sign of a number, it's more readable than your implementation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is exactly what are you looking for but below method will return false for {2,-3,17,-1,4,5,-1,8,-9,3}

```
public boolean alternance(int[] a) {
        boolean isAlternance = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if(a[i] * a[i+1] >= 0)
                isAlternance = false;
        }
        return isAlternance; 
    }
```

Comment: As per Sam's comment - Use java.lang.Math.signum()

Comment: I want it general for example this list {12,-3,3,-8,33,-2,1,-8,11,-3} it must be true but it gives false

Comment: Well it returns true for me:
`
  int [] i1 = {2,-3,17,-1,4,5,-1,8,-9,3};
  int [] i2 = {12,-3,3,-8,33,-2,1,-8,11,-3};  
  
  System.out.println("i1 result="+alternance(i1));
  System.out.println("i2 result="+alternance(i2));
`
Output:
`
i1 result=false
i2 result=true
`

Comment: It works fine indeed.  Might want to add `if (a.length <= 1) return false;` at the beginning, an empty array or an array with 1 element isn't alternating anything.

Comment: Could also add a `break;` after the `isAlternance = false;`, once you've found it's not alternating, there's no reason to check the rest of the array anymore :)

Comment: I prefer the early return because you avoid iterating the entire list as early as possible @Arjan

Comment: @BenKnoble I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean to just use `return false;` instead of the `isAlternance = false;` in the `for` loop, use `return true;` at the end of the method and throw the boolean out entirely, that'll work the same.  Some people consider it bad style though to return from a method in the middle of it.  Personally, I think it doesn't matter in such a short method anyway.

Comment: @ScaryWombat for the list {12,-3,3,-8,33,-2,1,-8,11,-3} it gives true not false :) this method works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory recursive solution

```
public class TestStackOverflowQuestion {

    // An array with 0 or 1 elements doesn't have alternating signs
    // An array has alternating signs if the next element has a different
    // sign as the current element, and if that's true for the rest of the array
    public static boolean alternance (int[] arr, int pos) {
        if (arr.length <= 1) return false;
        return (pos == arr.length - 1) ||
                (Math.signum(arr[pos]) !=  Math.signum(arr[pos + 1])
                    && alternance(arr, pos + 1)
                );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {};
        System.out.println(alternance(array, 0));  // false

        int[] array2 = {1};
        System.out.println(alternance(array2, 0)); // false

        int[] array3 = {1, -2, 3, -4};
        System.out.println(alternance(array3, 0)); // true

        int[] array4 = {-1, -2, 3, -4};
        System.out.println(alternance(array4, 0)); // false

        int [] array5 = {2,-3,17,-1,4,5,-1,8,-9,3};
        System.out.println(alternance(array5, 0)); // false

        int[] array6 = {12,-3,3,-8,33,-2,1,-8,11,-3};
        System.out.println(alternance(array6, 0)); // true
    }
}
```